# Postgresql Trigger causes server to be overloaded when it's triggered

Tags: sql, postgresql, odoo

I created a trigger on pgadmin, And when insert a new record on a table that trigers this trigger, I got error:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
```

500 Internal Server Error

## Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.  Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.

The trigger code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_user_id_from_hr_emplyee_into_namerel()
      RETURNS trigger LANGUAGE plpgsql
        AS $$ 

    DECLARE
        logged_user_id              INTEGER;
    BEGIN
      SELECT distinct resource.user_id FROM hr_employee emp 
    LEFT JOIN resource_resource resource ON resource.id=emp.resource_id  where emp.id=new.employee_id into logged_user_id ;  

     IF ( logged_user_id <> null) THEN 
     new.namerel=logged_user_id;
     END IF;

     RETURN null;
    END;
    $$;


    CREATE TRIGGER last_name_changes
      BEFORE Insert or UPDATE
      ON hr_payslip
      FOR EACH ROW
      EXECUTE PROCEDURE get_user_id_from_hr_emplyee_into_namerel();
```

Comment: your function always returns `NULL` ?

Answer (score 0):

PLPGSQL `SELECT`...`INTO` must always return no more than one row else you will get an error.

Answer (score 0):

After following changes it run for me.

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_user_id_from_hr_emplyee_into_namerel()
  RETURNS trigger LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS $$ 

DECLARE
    logged_user_id              INTEGER;
BEGIN
  SELECT distinct resource.user_id into logged_user_id FROM hr_employee emp 
LEFT JOIN resource_resource resource ON resource.id=emp.resource_id  where emp.id=new.employee_id;  

new.namerel=logged_user_id;
 --IF ( logged_user_id <> null) THEN 

 --END IF;

 RETURN new;
END;
$$;


CREATE TRIGGER last_name_changes
  BEFORE Insert or UPDATE
  ON hr_payslip
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE get_user_id_from_hr_emplyee_into_namerel();
```